# validation of a parameter of number type, in jsonschema

Tags: javascript

Tenho um parâmetro do tipo `number` e quero validar o tamanho, como posso fazer isso usando a função `maximum` em um `jsonschema`?

```
"type": ["number","null" ], "description": "Maximum Field Length - (23,8)"
```

Comment: Ué, não basta usar o `maximum` como você mesmo comentou? `{"type": "number", "maximum": 20}`

Comment: Olá Anderson, sim eu tenho que utilizar a função maximum, mas não sei como  implementar  (23,8) com tamnho maximo.

Comment: E o que significa "(23,8) como tamanho máximo"? O valor deve ser menor que 23.8?

Comment: 23 digitos e 8 casa decimais

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como comentou, você deseja validar que seu número possua até 23 caracteres na parte inteira e 8 caracteres na parte decimal. Você não faz isso com números, mas sim com *strings*.

O tipo `string` possui as validações `minLength`, `maxLength` e `pattern`:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "price": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 3,
      "maxLength": 32,
      "pattern": "^\\d{1,23}\\.\\d{1,8}$"
    }
  }
}
```

Desta forma, o JSON abaixo é válido:

```
{
  "price": "123.456789"
}
```

Mas o JSON abaixo não, pois possui mais de 8 caracteres na parte decimal.

```
{
  "price": "123.4567890123"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Acho que a melhor forma de validar isso seria na entrada dos dados com um

```
if (description.length< maxField)
```

Mas poderia fazer assim

```
{
  "type": "string",
  "minLength": 2,
  "maxLength": 3
}
```